# Where do I put my business logic in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, business-logic, laravel-4

In Laravel 3.2 I created a business logic namespace (folder) inside the application folder. Then I used the Autoloader to register the new namespace.

I want to do the same in Laravel 4 - I want to create custom namespace for my business logic. How do I register my business namespace and make available to the IoC?

Answer (score 4):

you can add any arbitrary folder in the app dir. Just be sure to add it to the "classmap" in you composer.json file. L4 doesn't scan for files/directories, it just looks to see what names have been loaded in the autoloader

Answer (score 0):

@Miguel Martinez to keep your controllers skinny you can put your business logic in models also.

Answer (score -1):

According to the laravel documentation controllers should contain business logic: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers

Comment: This is NOT what the docs say. Business logic should generally reside in Models if application specific otherwise libraries.